# How to get a specific record in a lookup table in Django

Tags: django

I'm building a Django app that manages client data. I store phone numbers, email addresses, addresses, etc., in lookup tables. I would like to create a queryset that
returns the primary numbers for all clients.

Here is an abbreviated version of the client table:

| id | last | first | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100426 | Smith | John | etc |
| 114988 | Johnson | Thomas | etc |

An example of the phones table:

| id | client_id | type_id | is_primary | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100426 | 1 | t | 427-567-8382 |
| 2 | 100426 | 2 | f | 427-567-7789 |
| 3 | 114988 | 1 | t | 914-223-4597 |

And finally, the phone_type table:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mobile |
| 2 | home |
| 3 | office |
| 4 | condo |

An extract of the client model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)     
    last = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(
        Phone,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
```

The phone model:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    client_id = models.IntegerField
    type_id = models.ForeignKey(
        PhoneType,        
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

And the phone_type:

```
class PhoneType(models.Model):
    id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=False, null=False)
```

My ClientListView:

```
class ClientListView(ListView):
    model = Client
    template_name = 'client/client_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'clients'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Client.objects.order_by('-id').filter(status_id=3).select_related(Phone)
```

The get_queryset function is a placeholder for now.

How can I replace the get_queryset function so that I'm able to list the primary phone number for each client based on the "is_primary" field in the phones table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) api with a queryset on top of it.

```
from django.models import Prefetch

Client.objects
    .prefetch_related(
        'phone_numbers',
        queryset=Phone.objects.filter(is_primary=True),
    )
```

But this would only work if your model is correctly defined.
In your `Phone` class, `client_id` seems to be a foreign key to `Client`.
So you should have:

```
Phone(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', related_name='phone_numbers')
```